# VBA run-time error '-2147352567 (800200009)'

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, outlook-filter

i'm trying to do a vba script for excel to search e-mail by subject or body throght the insert in a cell a data (A1), but during a running i've encountured the error '-2147352567 (800200009)' exactly in a for each loop.

i've tried to do a for cycle to check the condition but have the same error

```
Sub SearchEmails()

'Declare variables
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olItem As Object


Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Dim olFilter As String
olFilter = "[Subject] = '" & Range("A1").Value & "' OR [Body] = '" & Range("A1").Value & "'"


For Each olItem In olFolder.Items.Restrict(olFilter)
    'Do something with the email (e.g. print subject or delete)
    Debug.Print olItem.Subject
Next olItem

End Sub
```

Comment: Does cell `A1` of the active sheet contain any single quotes?

Comment: no, if i put a single quotes retrive me the error "impossible" analyze condition. Error in  <value>

Comment: Well maybe you should include what the value of `A1` is when it errors? or even better, then value of `olFilter`

Comment: Do you have any mail that has the exact subject line or body of  `12`? Or were you hoping to have it specify that it CONTAINS a `12`? `12` all by itself seems like a strange subject line.

Comment: yes the value now is 12 and is well readed in olFilter

Comment: i've tried also a perfect match with an email subject

Comment: yes i've send myself an email with this subject and body

Comment: post the data on your Excel file

Answer (score 0):

The error code tells that Outlook can't parse the condition passed to the `Restrict` method. If the Excel's value contains a single quote symbol the condition may not be well-formed. So, I'd recommend using the `Chr(34)` in the search criteria line instead of single quotes. See [Items.Restrict Method Returns error: "Cannot parse condition"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a2eab0b6-e724-4841-a0bf-0fb51caa3ebb/itemsrestrict-method-returns-error-cannot-parse-condition?forum=outlookdev) for more information.

When matching string properties, you can use either a pair of single quotes ('), or a pair of double quotes ("), to delimit a string that is part of the filter. For example, all of the following lines function correctly when the property is of type `String`:

```
sFilter = "[Subject] = 'Microsoft'"

sFilter = "[Subject] = " & Chr(34) & "Microsoft" & Chr(34)
```